# UIAlertView buttons don't work

Tags: uialertview, xcode4.4

I'm using an alert view to alert the user when the internet is not connected. I have two buttons in the alert view and they both don't seem to work. I already implemented the in the .h file. I used NSLog to check whether it responds when I click. It responds in the console, but does nothing when the button is pressed. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender 
   {
     if (![self connectedToNetwork])
     {
       UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Network Error!" message: @"You are not connected to the internet" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: @"Open Settings", nil];
       [internetAlert show];
     }
   }

- (void)alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  { 
     if (buttonIndex == 0)
     {
        NSLog(@"Ok clicked");
        HomeViewController *blah = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
       [self.view addSubview: blah.view];
     }

     else if (buttonIndex == 1)
     {
        NSLog(@"Settings clicked");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
     }
}
```

I used [self.contentView addSubview: blah.view] because I do not have a navigation controllers. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using wrong method for UIAlertView button clicked. you have to use another method of UIAlertView.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Please change to the following code and it will work.

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender 
{
    if (![self connectedToNetwork])
    {
        UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Network Error!" message: @"You are not connected to the internet" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: @"Open Settings", nil];
        [internetAlert show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ok clicked");
        HomeViewController *blah = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
        [self.view addSubview: blah.view];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Settings clicked");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: I tried that too. It doesn't work. My NSLog shows that clicking the buttons is actually giving me a response but I just can't change to another view.